# Turn off PC if bluetooth device is disconnected (proximity) or loses connection

Tags: windows, open-source, software-development, security

Is there such software, I've looked into Windows security features for such an option and it doesn't exist? I have found that you can unlock your PC with your Bluetooth device but can't shut it down if you leave your PC for instance.

My idea is as follows, I have a smartwatch *(or a phone)* and I keep it on me the whole time. I would like to just leave my PC and if my Bluetooth (watch) disconnects from my PC I would like it to shutdown.

- if Bluetooth device disconnects > **turn off PC**

Why? Many times I forget to turn off my computer either at work or at home and as I wear my watch or have my phone on, I can just connect it over with Bluetooth and if I leave for whatever reason it can just shut down *(or hibernate)*

- I have tried a basic google search for such software but haven't found one.

Comment: Are you really sure that's what you want? BT devices loose connection all the time, do you really want your PC to shut down while you're in the middle of something? Sounds like what you want is just an automatic shutdown when idle for a given amount of time, that should be built into any modern operating system.

Comment: @Sebastian depends, that is a good question, however I would need something like this. The closest thing so far that has been proposed is Dynamic Lock (Windows built-in)